# Regex for numbers and some characters

Tags: regex

I try to make regex for checking value which can contain numbers `0-9`, `()`, `+` and `-`. I tried this `var checkRegex = /^([0-9]+[ ()+-]*)$/gmi;` but it doesnt work https://regex101.com/r/eX6yH9/1. What did I do wrong?

Comment: In regex, you put the characters inside the character class `[]` to match any of them. The problem in your regex is that you've opened two. Also note that `\d` is the same as `0-9`. You don't need the outer `()` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct regex

```
^([0-9() +-]*)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX6yH9/2)**

Comment: @Heidel i have also included space..remove it if you don't want it

Comment: as @rock321987 said... if you don't want the space then use this `^([0-9()+-]*)$`

Answer (score 0):

in the link you provided there is a pattern dd-dd-dd-dd dunno if that was a coincidence the other answer is good

\d\d([ ()+-]\d\d)*

Comment: No, sorry, it was just an example. I really need just numbers, `()`, `+` and `-` in any order.